# Function for finding letters of the alphabet or punctuation?

Tags: javascript

Write a .js function named isAlpha that accepts a character
(i.e., string of length one) and returns true if it is a letter of the
alphabet, and false otherwise. The function should accept both
upper and lower case characters.

I though I had it, but I'm just not sure how to get it to accept punctuation and have it return as false.

```
var isAlpha = function(chr) {
    var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
    for(var i = 0; i < letters; i++){ 
        if(letter === letter[i]){
            return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: java is not js!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It could have been an honest mistake when applying  the tags (an errant click, for example). No need to jump on someone new for a tagging mistake. That being said, Kim, it works best if you describe *what exactly* is wrong. Being a "little unsure" is vague. Your question will gain the most traction the more specific you can be.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, am not jumping on no one...

Comment: "is a letter of the alphabet":  Based on your code, you must mean the English alphabet. JavaScript has no built-in way of distinguishing which characters are letters, let alone members of some language's alphabet in one of its writing systems. So, you're on the right track to spell out your alphabet, assuming you don't want the other English letter characters, which aren't in the "standard" alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

Much less to type (ASCII ftw):

```
var isAlpha = function(chr) {
    chr = chr.toUpperCase();

    if (chr < "A" || chr > "Z") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Was just going to check what kind of support JS had for ASCII -- nice and efficient. Based on the phrasing, I wonder if this is an interview question for OP. Should say, this accepts strings longer than length one, and will actually return `true` on a string like "abc245" -- the first letter determines the comparison. To fully satisfy the spec, it seems like the function should maybe complain/return false if more than one character is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
var isAlpha = function(chr) {
    chr = chr.toLowerCase();
    var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
    for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){ 
        if(chr == letters[i]){
            return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: You have the idea in your code, but you have errors. Ex: 'letter' was never defined.